# how can I extract single values from a JSON string in python without parsing it to Javascript object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response - `[{'address': '123 Any Street', 'province': 'ON', 'postal_code': 'L1P 2X2', 'co': 'BURL'}]`

I would want to get individual values from this response like address = 123 Any Street, Province = ON etc in python. I want to use these values to be passed while rendering the template.

```
print(qry_activity)
if (qry_activity is not None):
    results_activity = [{
        "address": row.address,
        "province": row.province,
        "postal_code": row.postal_code,
        "co": row.co
    }
        for row in qry_activity.all()]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You already have JSON array with single item in response, just parse it using `json.loads()` and obtain first element, no need to build dict manually.

Comment: `results_activity = list(qry_activity.all())`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Actually `json` won't parse it correctly as it is not a valid json (using only single quotes). I would suggest `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I am getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'" error when trying to use json.loads()

Comment: @no_hex, yes, you're right, I've missed single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the input you're getting to a dictionary without the need to actually construct it by yourself using `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`:

If you want to use `json.loads` you will need to fix the format, as using single quotes for the keys in JSON is invalid:

```py
import json

json_response = "[{'address': '123 Any Street', 'province': 'ON', 'postal_code': 'L1P 2X2', 'co': 'BURL'}]"
json_response = json_response.replace('\'', '\"')

dictionary_result = json.loads(json_response)[0]

print(type(dictionary_result))
print(dictionary_result)
```

Which results in:

```py
<class 'dict'>
[{'address': '123 Any Street', 'province': 'ON', 'postal_code': 'L1P 2X2', 'co': 'BURL'}]
```

Or use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method which takes a string and *literally* evaluating it as is:

```py
import ast

json_response = "[{'address': '123 Any Street', 'province': 'ON', 'postal_code': 'L1P 2X2', 'co': 'BURL'}]"

dictionary_result = ast.literal_eval(json_response)[0]

print(type(dictionary_result))
print(dictionary_result)
```

Which outputs the same as the first example.

---

If you're getting a list, and not a string that represents one, you could just retrieve the first element:

```py
json_response = [{'address': '123 Any Street', 'province': 'ON', 'postal_code': 'L1P 2X2', 'co': 'BURL'}]

dictionary_result = json_response[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a list, so I tried this and it worked - address = results_activity[0].get('address')